# Weird JAVA Boolean Evaluation Issue

Tags: java

Hi I have the following code:

```
  boolean result = someexpression();

            if(!result)
            {
            System.out.println("False..."); 
            }
            if (result); 
            {
                System.out.println("True");
            }
```

It prints both (False and true)
I also tried using things like

```
     if(result==true)
```

but that doesnt seem to do the trick. No matter what the value of the variable it just enters the condition.?? I am using eclipse and this only happens at a specific portion.

Comment: wahh waha wavee.. a good one..

Comment: You might want to try installing the FindBugs plugin for Eclipse.  I think it will detect this one.  http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (result);
```

Remove the `;` at the end of this line.

With the `;`, it means "if `result` is `true`, then do nothing". The block that contains the next statement isn't part of the `if` and will always be executed. It's exactly the same as this:

```
if (result)   // if result is true
    ;         // then do nothing

System.out.println("True");  // is always executed
```

Comment: After all the manipulations and alterations. Its amazing how sleep deprivation could make you overlook these issues.Thanks for the instant reply.

Comment: this is the sort of "error" that I'd like the compiler to catch, although I understand why it doesn't.  It also happens to be one of those very hard errors to see in your own code!

Comment: @David Try static code checking tools such as Checkstyle, Findbugs or PMD. Those will most likely catch this kind of error.

Answer (score 7):

You have a rogue semi-colon at the end of your if statement.

```
if (result);
```

This makes your code evaluate to

```
if (result) {

}
{
    System.out.println("True");
}
```

where the second pair of `{}` denotes a code block which always gets executed since it's not part of the if control block anymore. So get rid of that semi-colon (which I assume is not what you meant to put there)!